# takes integers as arguments and prints the sum of those numbers but getting command not found error

Tags: ubuntu, unix

I want to take arguments from command line and print the sum of the integer. But if there is no argument given then it should give me total as 0.

Example vi sum.sh contains below code

```
total=0

for i in $@; do
  (( total+=i ))
done

echo "The total is $total"
```

`bash sum.sh`
Then this should give me output as 0

Similarly if I give `bash sum.sh 1 2`
then output coming as 3 which is correct but its not working when there is no arguments given.

I am getting error `total: command not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
total=0

for i in $@; do
  total=$(($total+$i ))
done

echo "The total is $total"
```

When you use the value of a variable, it needs to be preceded by a dollarsign.
In top of that, you need `$((...))` to perform calculations.

**Edit:** example
I have put this piece of script in a file, called `test.sh` and did the following test (with its result):

```
Prompt> sh test.sh 1 2 6
The total is 9
```

Comment: Thanks for this but when I am using this logic I am not getting sum of the integers instead getting ```total: command not found error``` only. And even if user doesn't provide any arguments then the sum should be 0 and it should display as 0 in output

Comment: ??? Are you sure? Did you put all dollarsigns and brackets on the right place? (Don't type the script yourself, use copy/paste)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. ACtually there was spaces in my code